# How to use a object extern method in a main in C?

Tags: c, oop

I'm trying to do a simple "Oriented object" programm in C and I come from Java. I did some research and reading online and I came with this code :
*Declaring my base class*

```
#ifndef FIGURE_H
#define FIGURE_H
struct figure{
    int(*m_draw) (struct figure* oref);
    int(*m_move) (struct figure* oref, int x, int y);
    int(*m_resize) (struct figure* oref, int x, int y);
    int(*m_rotate) (struct figure* oref, int angle);
    int(*m_erase) (struct figure* oref);
    int(*m_show) (struct figure* oref);

};
extern void init_figure(struct figure* oref);

extern int draw (struct figure* oref);
//... so on

#endif //FIGURE
```

So this is the header file of my main structure called `Figure` I'm not really sure about the last part where I define all method extern I think it's wrong. Then I want to do a `figure_x` so I a `figure_x.c` I did the following code to redefine the methods
*figure_x.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "figure.h"

int f_draw(struct  figure* oref){
    printf("Hey I'm an awesome figure (%p), I bet you never have seen something like that b4", oref);
    //idk what to do but when I tried with void I had error and with int it's fine lol help me
    return -1;
}

int f_move(int x, int y, struct  figure* oref){
    return -1;
}

//so on for each method defined in the figure structure
void init_figure (struct figure* oref)
{
    oref->m_draw = f_draw;
    oref->m_move = f_move;
    oref->m_resize = f_resize;
    oref->m_rotate = f_rotate;
    oref->m_erase  = f_erase;
    oref->m_show   = f_show;
}
```

And finally I create a `main.c` where I chose to use a static declaration and usage of my objet like this:
*main.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "figure.h"
int main() {
    //create a fig
    struct figure fig;
    //init the fig
    init_figure(&fig);
    fig.m_draw(&fig);
    fig.m_move(&fig, 1, 2);
    fig.m_resize(&fig, 3, 4);
    fig.m_rotate(&fig, 5);
    fig.m_erase(&fig);
    fig.m_show(&fig);
    return 0;
}
```

Now I get the following error :

```
C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Temp\ccSxcgqa.o:main.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `init_figure'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My question is how can be `init_figure` undefined even if I use the key word `extern`

Comment: please provide your build command

Comment: I'm using `Clion` from `Jetbrains` so I just type `gcc main.c` in the terminal of `Clion` am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12574400/1505939

Comment: so if I understand I also need to `#define figure_x.c` in `main.c`

Comment: no, try "gcc main.c figure_x.c". The error you get is the linker saying "I don't know where the function definition for `init_figure` is". That's in figure_x.c, so include that in your build line. I can never remember if the order of the files here matters, I don't think so. Order matters for linking object files.

Comment: @yano it's working the error isn't here anymore